# Wordpress Facebook Share - Open graph tags in body

Tags: wordpress, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

I am using a plugin in wordpress theme for sharing activities of user. But when i am sharing it is not taking right image,title and description.

When i searched everyone is suggesting to use Facebook debugger and open graph tags.

I tried by using open graph tags to set values. Open graph tags work well in header section when i hard coded all values. but when i use meta tags in body it is not taking meta tags value.

But problem with me is i have values which would be set in body.

I have tried 2-3 plugins. in all plugin, i am facing same problem.

Is there any way by which i can set value into meta tags inside body?

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: Only if you create your own plugin that will output og tags in head of your page. But if you have plugins that should already do that and they aren't doing that, try contacting the plugin author.

Comment: they are suggesting to use open graph and facebook debugger.

Comment: why would you add open graph metatags in the body?

Comment: I have dynamic images, title and description for each activity. how could i set different images, title and description each time for different acitivity?

Comment: open graph tags are not supposed to be used for dynamic images. still not sure why you don´t set the tags i the head section. each page must have a specific/permanent url anyway, else the og tags don´t make sense.

Comment: Ok. only url is specific , but if i want to set custom image and title dynamically then how could it possible??

Answer (score 0):

> Remove your Plugins and use this, Facebook share post must be add
>   meta. Please Try, Put function.php

```
add_action('wp_head','add_meta_function');

function  add_meta_function(){
    if(is_single()){
        global $post;       
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="'.get_permalink().'" />';
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.home_url().'/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/4569952.png" />';

        echo '<meta property="og:title" content="'.get_the_title().'" />';  
        echo '<meta property="og:description" content="'.substr($post->post_content,0,100).'" />';
    }

}
```

> Put your single page and list page.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>" target="_blank">
Share
</a>
```